# VBA to add a row to the bottom of the table and insert Rich Text Content Control

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a form in Word 2013. In it are various tables and I want users to be able to add a row to the bottom of the table. I have done this with the following code:

```
`Dim oTable As table
Dim oCell As Cell
Dim oPrevRow as Row, oNewRow As Row
Dim iColumn As Long
Set oTable = ActiveDocument.tables (1)
Set oPrevRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.Rpws.Count)
oTable.Rows.Add
Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.rows.Count)`
```

What I want is for all 7 cells in that new row to have Rich Text Content Control inserted into them. How do I do this?

Comment: Does the previous row also have the same content controls?

Comment: Hi Cindy, yes it does.

Comment: There are three basic ways this can be handled: 1) copy/paste the last row, which will include the content controls; 2) save this row as an AutoText (BuildingBlock) entry and insert as required; 3) (Assuming Word 2013 or later) Put the table in a repeating section content control, so that it automatically generates a new row when the user clicks the +. The code Paul has provided is a variation on 1...

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work with a table bookmarked as 'TblBkMk' anywhere in the document body. Comments in the code show how you could test for a particular table instead. Simply add the code to the 'ThisDocument' code module of the document or its template. The macro triggers when you exit the last content control in the table. The code also provides for the document to have 'read-only' or 'filling in forms' protection (add the password to the code where indicated, if you use one)

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
'The following code conditionally adds a new row, with content controls, to the designated table.
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Prot As Long
Const Pwd As String = "" 'Insert password (if any) here
'Bookmarking the table provides the flexibility of being able to deal with the addition/deletion
' of other tables before the one we want to process.
Const StrBkMk As String = "TblBkMk"
'Exit if we're not in a table - we don't really need this is using a bookmarked table,
' but it's a safeguard against the bookmark having been expanded/moved.
If CCtrl.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then Exit Sub
With ActiveDocument
  If .Bookmarks.Exists(StrBkMk) = False Then
    MsgBox "The table bookmark: '" & StrBkMk & "' is missing." & vbCr & _
    "Please add it to the relevant table before continuing.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
End With
With CCtrl
  'Check that the Content Control is within our bookmarked table's range.
  If .Range.InRange(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(StrBkMk).Range) = False Then Exit Sub
  ' One could test for a particular table instead, in which case all the code dealing
  ' with wdWithInTable & StrBkMk can be deleted. For example:
  'If .Range.InRange(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range) = False Then Exit Sub
  'Get the number of ContentControls in the table
  i = .Range.Tables(1).Range.ContentControls.Count
  'Get our ContentControl's index # in the table
  j = ActiveDocument.Range(.Range.Tables(1).Range.Start, .Range.End).ContentControls.Count
  'Check that we're using the last content control
  If i <> j Then Exit Sub
End With
'Solicit user input
If MsgBox("Add new row?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
With ActiveDocument
  ' Un-protect the document, if applicable
  Prot = .ProtectionType
  If .ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    Prot = .ProtectionType
    .Unprotect Password:=Pwd
  End If
  With Selection.Tables(1).Rows
    'Insert an empty paragraph after our table, then replace it with a replica of the last row
    With .Last.Range
      .Next.InsertBefore vbCr
      .Next.FormattedText = .FormattedText
    End With
    'Reset all content controls in the new last row
    For Each CCtrl In .Last.Range.ContentControls
      With CCtrl
        If .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then .Checked = False
        If .Type = wdContentControlRichText Or .Type = wdContentControlText Then .Range.Text = ""
        If .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList Then .DropdownListEntries(1).Select
        If .Type = wdContentControlComboBox Then .DropdownListEntries(1).Select
        If .Type = wdContentControlDate Then .Range.Text = ""
      End With
    Next
  End With
  'Update the bookmarked range
  .Bookmarks.Add Name:=StrBkMk, Range:=Selection.Tables(1).Range
  ' Re-protect the document, if applicable
  .Protect Type:=Prot, Password:=Pwd
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks macropod, I have put that in but keep getting an error on the following line:
.Next.InsertBefore vbCr

Comment: The code above has been posted on other forums without anyone ever coming back with such an error. What wrap format does your table use and what follows it?

Comment: Hi macropod, it uses none at the moment and a second table follows it. ah, now I've changed the wrapping to around and it works - thank you

Comment: It's 'around' wrapping I'd have suspected to be the culprit - unless perhaps that's what the following table also has.